# What is the correct KVM VM vCPU config in cockpit for proper load balance on physical CPUs

Tags: linux, redhat, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, vcpu

I have dual CPU server. I want to run some VMs on top of it. While configuring VMs thru cockpit (on redhat 8.0). I cam across this screen:

[image]

I just want to allocate 8 cores with 4 on each physical CPU. I am confused with the side bar. It shows same choices for sockets, cores per socket and Threads per socket (1,2,4,8)

How should this be defined? What are the correct values for sockets cores and threads on this screen? Looked up and found no documentation.

Thank you.

details:

CPU:

```
# lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              56
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-55
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  14
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               79
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             1617.634
BogoMIPS:            4794.27
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            35840K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-13,28-41
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   14-27,42-55
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti intel_ppin ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap intel_pt xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts flush_l1d
```

nodeinfo...

```
# virsh nodeinfo
CPU model:           x86_64
CPU(s):              56
CPU frequency:       3070 MHz
CPU socket(s):       1
Core(s) per socket:  14
Thread(s) per core:  2
NUMA cell(s):        2
```

from the net I understood 56 above is the total number of vCPU which can be allocated. Is that correct?

Comment: the sockets/cores/threads is the *architecture* the guest system will see and has no bearing on how the physical CPU(s) will be used - at least, I don't think so, I can "expose" multiple sockets to a guest on a host with a single socket

Answer (score 1):

The numbers of cores per socket you define for the VM should, in most cases, have no real reflection on how the VM workload is spread across the physical CPUs in the host: it’s mainly useful for proprietary licenses, where “per-socket” pricing used to be a thing. The recommendation is to not touch that setting unless you need to.

In fact you usually would *not* want to unnecessarily force the workload of a single VM to be spread across multiple physical CPUs, since NUMA traditionally has been a bottleneck for memory and caching. [Red Hat’s documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/optimizing-virtual-machine-performance-in-rhel_monitoring-and-managing-system-status-and-performance) gives advice on how to manually pin vCPUs to NUMA nodes, but their example is a machine that’s larger than would fit within a single NUMA node on the host.

Finally: no, the number of logical CPUs available to you (sockets * cores * threads) are not the maximum number of virtual CPUs you can assign overall. It is good to keep the amount of overprovisioning per host in mind, though, as it will add to the latency each VM experiences as it waits for a slice of CPU time.